# How to create a Date Of birth field using 3 pickers from react native dropdown picker.?

Tags: react-native, react-native-dropdown-picker

Greeting Everyone.
Here is the link using react native dropdown date, i want to create something like this using drop down picker. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dropdown-date-demo-gbm2k. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use any dropdown library and add the `Picker` component separately for a day, month and year to the states, then handle with the same `formdate` method, one library is:
https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker

Also, there is this library for date picker:
https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker

Implemented examples are already there. Hope this works :)

Comment: But Picker has a problem when we click on the middle portion of it, it crashes the app. I had that issue, which is the reason why i selected react native drop down picker